# Why can the simplest C++ code not be compiled?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, temporary-objects, type-deduction

```
template<class CharType>
struct MyString
{
    MyString()
    {}

    MyString(CharType*)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    char* narrow_str = 0;
    MyString<char>(narrow_str); // error C2040
}
```

My compiler is VC++ 2013 RC.

The simplest code cannot be compiled because of the error C2040.

> error C2040: 'narrow_str' : 'MyString' differs in levels of
>   indirection from 'char *'

Why?

Comment: What you think is a constructor call is actually not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this is actually not being parsed as a constructor call but as a variable definition. The problem is you already defined a variable `narrow_str`. You may have already known this but you can easily fix this by giving it a name.

```
template<class CharType>
struct MyString
{
    MyString()
    {}

    MyString(CharType*)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    char* narrow_str = 0;
    MyString<char> ns(narrow_str); // error C2040
}
```

BTW this is also the source of the most vexing parse which occurs when this type of syntax is used in a function argument.

To be honest though I'm surprised that you got a different error because both g++ and clang gave me a clear error.

Answer (score 0):

your syntax in creating a struct is wrong .
change

```
    MyString<char>(narrow_str); // error C2040
```

to

```
    MyString<char> myString(narrow_str);
```

will be ok.

Comment: I think he knows that he could do that, but is wondering why the first one doesn't compile, he thinks he's creating a temporary